# When did the physicians realize that knowledge of internal anatomy can help in healing the patient?

Tags: history, ancient-medicine, anatomy

When did the physicians realize that knowledge of internal anatomy can help in healing the patient?
I know that human dissections were rare until 15-16c. But there were earlier cultures like the Egyptians, who regularly dissected bodies in order to make mummification, but it seems that this did not affected their medicine. 
I personally study cuneiform texts and in their medicine the larger concept is the belief in external elements (most often demons), who influence the patient.